# Non- linear least square error in R

Tags: r, regression

I am a beginner in R and I am trying find the parameters `(b0,b1,ta)` of the function:

```
1/n*sum(exp(b0+b1*x1)*log(1+Y^(ta)))
```

but I keep getting the error:

**R output:**

```
Error in qr(.swts * gr) : dims [product 3] do not match the length of object [25]
```

In addition: **Warning message:**

In `.swts * gr` : longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Can someone please help solve this issue.

```
set.seed(56)  
x1 =runif(25)
y11 = runif(25)  
n= 25 
b0=1    
b1=1    
ta=0.5 
Y = runif(25)   
dat= data.frame(y11,x1)    
nls( y11~ 1/n*sum(exp(b0+b1*x1)*log(1+Y^(ta))),data = dat ,c(b0=1,b1=1,ta=0.5))
```

Comment: Your problem is with the `sum()` function. Are you sure that your formula is correct? Your sum collapses the vector of predictor information stored in the `x`'s into a single number but your outcome is of length 25.

Comment: Yes i am sure my formula is correct given by : '1/n * sum(  exp( b0 + b1*x1)* log(1+Y^ta )'  which is equivalent to the 'mean( exp( b0 + b1*x1)* log(1+Y^ta)'

Comment: The mean is one number. But you are modeling 25. Try to remove the sum and see what happens

Comment: It works without the sum but my formula includes a sum

Comment: the output of nls function gives ta <0 which contradicts since it is always > 0

Comment: I'm guessing your formula has the mean on the left-hand-side. But in your formula in R you are linking the individual predictors to the individual outcomes.

Comment: there is a summation on the left which is supposed to converge to 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possibilities here depending on what it is that you want. They are not equivalent.

**1)** Firstly we could minimize the square of the difference of the means using `optim` ilke this.

```
f <- function(par, x1, Y, y11) {
 b0 <- par[1]
 b1 <- par[2]
 ta <- par[3]
 (mean(exp(b0+b1*x1)*log(1+Y^(ta))) - mean(y11))^2
}

set.seed(56)  
x1 =runif(25)
y11 = runif(25)  
Y = runif(25)   

optim(c(1,1,0.5), f, x1 = x1, Y = Y, y11 = y11)
```

giving:

```
$`par`
[1] 0.2307641 0.8844143 1.1084035

$value
[1] 1.544321e-08

$counts
function gradient 
      56       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

**2)** Alternately we could minimize the sum of squares of the differences of `y11` and the right hand side without the `1/n*sum` like this:

```
dat <- data.frame(x1, Y, y11)
nls( y11 ~ exp(b0+b1*x1)*log(1+Y^(ta)), dat, list(b0=1,b1=1,ta=0.5))
```

giving:

```
Nonlinear regression model
  model: y11 ~ exp(b0 + b1 * x1) * log(1 + Y^(ta))
   data: dat
     b0      b1      ta 
0.08043 0.10121 0.35551 
 residual sum-of-squares: 1.585

Number of iterations to convergence: 8 
Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.578e-06
```

Comment: Thanks @G.Grothendieck